# SQL DataReader isn't reading all columns and isn't writing to file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Even though my `DataReader` seems to be correctly interpreting the values(almost), it's missing a column, not writing to the file, and at the last row it is throwing a

`+      base    {"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."}    System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}`

as it exits the `while sqlReader.Read()` loop.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "use sis_comparison_data select reg_batch_uid, user_id_reg, reg_first, reg_mid, reg_last, reg_email, reg_stu_id, registrar_row_status from sis_temp where bb_row_status is null";

string bb_users = @"C:\BB_USERS.bbd";


  using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(bb_users, false))
  {
    file.WriteLine("SYSTEM_ROLE|INSTITUTION_ROLE|EXTERNAL_PERSON_KEY|USER_ID|PASSWD|FIRSTNAME|MIDDLENAME|LASTNAME|EMAIL|STUDENT_ID|ROW_STATUS");
    using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
            while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    file.WriteLine("none|student|", sqlReader["reg_batch_uid"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["user_id_reg"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_stu_id"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_first"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_mid"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_last"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_email"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_stu_id"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["registrar_row_status"].ToString());
                }
                sqlReader.Close();
            }             
   }
```

My code is creating the file and writing the first line, and it's writing the `"none|student|"` just nothing else after it. And for whatever reason it isn't picking up the `registrar_row_status` column.

The SQL query works as I've been doing all of the SQL scripting before implementing it into the code.

This is what the debug output shows while stepping through code.

```
+       sqlReader   {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader}   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        sqlReader["reg_batch_uid"]  "johndoe"   object {string}
        sqlReader["reg_email"]  "jdoe@com.edu"  object {string}
        sqlReader["reg_first"]  "john"  object {string}
        sqlReader["reg_last"]   "doe"   object {string}
        sqlReader["reg_mid"]    ""  object {string}
        sqlReader["reg_stu_id"] "1234567"   object {string}
        sqlReader["user_id_reg"]    "johndoe"   object {string}
```

As you can see, it's missing `registrar_row_status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your first argument to that overload of `StreamWriter.WriteLine` needs to be a format string. See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/60scc1f1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I was confused by what you were saying but I see what you're talking about. I didn't intend to overload writeline so I'll just concatenate that first argument and see if it fixes my issue. What a nob mistake on my part :P edit: that was it, how silly of me. the row_status doesn't show in the debug output but still gets written which is good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 file.WriteLine("none|student|" + sqlReader["reg_batch_uid"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["user_id_reg"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_stu_id"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_first"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_mid"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_last"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_email"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["reg_stu_id"].ToString() + "|" + sqlReader["registrar_row_status"].ToString());
```